# Using CASE as a join condition in Hive

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to run a query in Hive where I run a join based on a case statement. For some reason, I'm having problems on lines 7 and 8. I have not been able to resolve the error which is

line 7: Expected: AND, AS, BETWEEN, DIV, ILIKE, IN, IREGEXP, IS, LIKE, NOT, OR, REGEXP, RLIKE CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

line 8: Encountered: AS Expected: AND, BETWEEN, DIV, ILIKE, IN, IREGEXP, IS, LIKE, NOT, OR, REGEXP, RLIKE CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

```
select * from dra_record_set.mark_set inv 
                        INNER JOIN innerdb.name_set roll_table
                        on inv.record_id = roll_table.ply_record_id AND
                        roll_table.date =
                            (CASE
                                WHEN inv.purchase_day>0 AND inv.purhcase_date BETWEEN roll_table.discount_start_dt AND roll_table.discount_end_dt) THEN inv.purchase_date
                                ELSE WHEN (CONCAT(inv.purchase_yr,inv.purchase_mo,(CAST("15")AS INT))) AS temp_var BETWEEN roll_table.discount_start_dt AND roll_table.discount_end_dt) THEN inv.purchase_date
                            END AS temp_pur_dt)
                        WHERE inv.inroll_discount_eligible_flag =1
                        limit 10
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. A non-working query is rarely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`case` is an *expression*.  It returns a value.  Your seems to be more like a macro substitution for SQL code.

Remove the `case` and just use boolean logic:

```
from dra_record_set.mark_set inv join
     innerdb.name_set roll_table
     on inv.record_id = roll_table.ply_record_id and
        ( (inv.purchase_day > 0 and
          inv.purhcase_date between roll_table.discount_start_dt and roll_table.discount_end_dt
          ) or
          (inv.purchase_day <= 0 and
           CONCAT(inv.purchase_yr, inv.purchase_mo, 15) between roll_table.discount_start_dt AND roll_table.discount_end_dt
          )
        )
```

Comment: we need check whether roll_table.date fits the second condition with the two betweens. you are missing that here...

Comment: @algorythms . . . This was my best guess on what you might mean by that second condition -- the code doesn't make sense.  But the same idea holds, whatever the logic is.